# Trying to Fetch all Firebase Users in SwiftUI but only getting one, and not the Signed In User?

Tags: firebase, swiftui

> I am trying to Display a property from All Users in Firebase Database. I get a print message with all the users listed, however only one is returned on the view and it is not even the logged in user?

**My View**

```
struct LeagueView: View {
//MARK: - PROPERTIES
@EnvironmentObject var userInfo: UserInfo
@ObservedObject var viewModel = LeagueViewModel()
@AppStorage("isDarkMode") private var isDarkMode = false
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

@State private var animateColor = false

//MARK: - BODY
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(viewModel.users) { user in
                    // LeagueCell(userLeagueViewModel: user, animateColor: $animateColor)
                    HStack {
                        Text(user.username)
                        
                    }
                }
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    animateColor.toggle()
                })
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Welcome \(userInfo.user.username)", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: signoutButton)
        .onAppear(perform: {
            //userInfo.getAllUsers()
            viewModel.getLeagueUsers()
        })
    }//: NavView
}

var signoutButton: some View {
    Button(action: {
        userInfo.isUserAuthenticated = .signedOut
    }, label: {
        Text("Signout")
    })
}
```

}

**MY View Model**

```
class LeagueViewModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var users = [LeagueUserModel]()


func getLeagueUsers() {
    Firestore.firestore().collection(FBKeys.CollectionPath.users)
        .getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("DEBUG: Couldnt Fetch Users \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                for document in snapshot!.documents {
                    let users = [FBUser.init(documentData: document.data())]
                    let nonOptionalUsers = users.compactMap({ $0 })
                    print("DEBUG: Before - \(self.users)")
                    self.users = nonOptionalUsers.map(LeagueUserModel.init)
                    print("DEBUG: After - \(nonOptionalUsers)")
                }
            }
        
    }
        
}
```

}

> I have tried using a few different variations of calling the function but nothing seems to be working, this is one variation. I have been searching all over online for the past few days but haven't found anything. I imagine it is something small I am missing.
>
> Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this to get all the users in the firebase document path. Note, you probably will have to adjust a few things:

```
func getLeagueUsers() {
    Firestore.firestore().collection(FBKeys.CollectionPath.users)
        .getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("DEBUG: Couldnt Fetch Users \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                for document in snapshot!.documents {
                    let fbuser = FBUser(documentData: document.data())
                    print("DEBUG: Before fbuser: \(fbuser)")
                    self.users.append(LeagueUserModel(fbuser)) // <-- or something similar
                    print("DEBUG: After users: \(self.users)")
                }
                print("DEBUG: final users: \(self.users)")
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so MUCH!! Sorry for the late reply, all I had to add was an if let to unwrap the fbuser and IT WORKED!!! lol thank you so much!!